# Add 6 months to date until it is bigger than today

Tags: php, date, for-loop

I have a date for example: 2014-06-19 and I need a loop where it will add 6 months until it is bigger than today?

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `while` loop:

```php
$today = new DateTime('today');
$input = new DateTime('2014-06-19');

while ($today > $input) {
    $input->modify('+6 months');
}

echo $input->format('Y-m-d'); // 2016-12-19
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/614590)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `DateTime` and `DateInterval` objects:

```
$input_date = new \DateTime("2014-06-19");
$six_months = new \DateInterval("P6M");
$now = new \DateTime();
$limit = (new \DateTime())->sub($six_months);

while ($input_date < $now && $input_date <= $limit) {
    $input_date->add($six_months);
}

print_r($input_date->format("Y-m-d"));  // 2016-06-19
```

Comment: `2016-06-19` is not bigger than today. Or have I misunderstood OP?

Comment: in your case `2016-06-19` should be the "maximum allowable" date value, because the next value `2016-12-19` coming after it is bigger than today. So, we should stop the loop at `2016-06-19`

Comment: But `2016-06-19` is not bigger than today. Apparently  I don't understand OP's need. Let's see if he updates his question

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "2009-01-31 +1 month" ) ); // PHP:  2009-03-03
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "2009-01-31 +2 month" ) ); // PHP:  2009-03-31
?>
```

[php.net month issue](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php#111989)

Answer (score -1):

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->modify('+6 months');
echo $datetime->format('d');
```

or

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
echo $datetime->format('d');
```

or in PHP version 5.4+

```
echo (new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval('P6M'))->format('d');
```